# Python Django Datetime objects and literal strings vs variables

Tags: python, django, datetime, variables

I am transferring some legacy posts into a new Django blog. In my script, I have the following code:

```
    Entry.objects.create(
        title=['title'], slug=['slug'], chron_date=['chron_date'],
        clock='23:59:59', content=['content'])
```

The problem is that the date, time, and datetime fields all refuse to take a variable, or, they all treat the intended variable as a literal string, which generates errors. The only solution I’ve found is the one you see for clock, where I have to hard code a literal string. This means I have to go back through the posts one at a time to manually correct the dates and times.

Questions:
Why do the date and time objects work this way?
Is this the only workaround, or am I missing something that would allow me to use a variable and loop through all the actual dates and get them imported?

Thanks.

Comment: Post the model for Entry? Is clock a datefield? If you need a default, just call datetime.datetime.today?

Comment: @Eric clock is a time field and chron_date is the date field. I didn't want a default, I wanted the actual date and time from the original post to be preserved.

Comment: We would need to see your `Post` model with its field types and also the data type of your legacy source. Are you reading from an old database, a text file, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

clock=datetime.strptime('23:59:59', '%H:%M:%S').time()
```

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear. I got the 23:59:59 default working, but that's NOT what I want. I want the actual date and time from the original post to be preserved in the new site.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you, but never mind. Turns out there was another, deeper error causing all of this. Once I realized and fixed that, all this went away, too. But thanks for trying!